# How to set colour for toc links in R markdown document?

Tags: markdown, r-markdown

I'm trying to create a R markdown document and use custom colours for the links in the document. This works for external links, but not for the ones in the table of contents. It was my understanding that the `linkcolor` attribute should take care of that, but it doesn't work for me.

Here's my workflow:

Document:

```
---
title: "test"
output:
    pdf_document:
      toc: true
linkcolor: red
urlcolor: red
citecolor: red
---

# Foo

## Fooo

foo foo foo [link](https://duckduckgo.com)

# Bar

## Bar Bar

bar bar bar
```

To render, I'm using `rmarkdown::render` in R. In Unix systems, you can just run this line (provided you saved the given example as `doc.Rmd`):

```
echo "rmarkdown::render('doc.Rmd', output_file='doc.pdf')" | R
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out.

Using the `hyperref` package allows all sorts of link customisation.

Example header:

```
---
title: "test"
output:
    pdf_document:
      toc: true
header-includes:
    - \usepackage {hyperref}
    - \hypersetup {colorlinks = true, linkcolor = red, urlcolor = red}
---
```

Comment: This works for me.  Any reason why just using `linkcolor: blue` for `pdf_document` doesn't work?  I am using TinyTex as my latex program.

Comment: You should be able to modify this in the `hypersetup` options. So `- \hypersetup {colorlinks = true, linkcolor = blue, urlcolor = red}` in your case. At least that works for me, using `pdflatex`

Comment: ! Undefined control sequence.
 \hypersetup {colorlinks = true, linkcolor = blue, urlcolor = blue, bookmarks = true, bookmarksopen = false}

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simpler solution using the `toccolor` option:

```
---
output: pdf_document
toc: true
toccolor: 'red'
---

# section 1
# section 2
```

[image: Compiled pdf]